# Push data on array with two levels

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anybody knows or give me some directions on how to populate a multidimensional data array:
I have one data array with this:

```
dataTable = [
    {section: 'section1', item: 'item1', num: 0},
    {section: 'section2', item: 'item1', num: 0},
    {section: 'section3', item: 'item1', num: 0},
    {section: 'section3', item: 'item2', num: 0}
];
```

I need to populate that 2D array with this data on the following format:

```
tableToLoad = [{
    sectionNum: 1,
    sectionTitle: "section1",
    data: [{
        level: 1,
        title: item1,
        child: false
    }]
}, {
    sectionNum: 2,
    sectionTitle: "section2",
    data: [{
        level: 1,
        title: item1,
        child: false
    }]
}, {
    sectionNum: 3,
    sectionTitle: "section3",
    data: [{
        level: 1,
        title: item1,
        child: false
    }, {
        level: 1,
        title: item2,
        child: false
    }]
}];
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Then please post that code. Is there a way to deduce the index in the `tableToLoad` from the data in a given object from `dataTable`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var tableToLoad = [], tableSecIdx = {};

dataTable.forEach(function(item) {

    //find the sec index
    var idx = tableSecIdx[item.section];

    if (!idx) {

        //push a new one
        tableToLoad.push({
            sectionNum : tableToLoad.length + 1,
            sectionTitle : item.section,
            data : []
        });

        //remember the idx
        tableSecIdx[item.section] = idx = tableToLoad.length - 1;
    }

    //push the data
    tableToLoad[idx].data.push({
        level : 1,
        title : item.item,
        child : false
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Zke8/2/

Comment: That's not enough. The two entries for `section3` are expected to be joined together.

Comment: If I have more than one entries on section 1, it breaks the same section in two parts. One with the first item and other with the rest.

Comment: Hi Bergi. on each section that have more than one item I need to joined together too.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have one problem with the first section. If it has only one item, no problem. But if it has more then one it breakes the  sections in two parts. One section with the first item, and the same section again with the remaining items. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

try following way:

```
var tableToLoad = [], dataMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.length; i++) {
  var data = dataTable[i];
  if (dataMap[data.section]) {
    dataMap[data.section].data.push({
      level: 1,
      title: data.item,
      child: false
    });
    continue;
  }

  var newData = {
    sectionNum: tableToLoad.length + 1,
    sectionTitle: data.section,
    data: [{
      level: 1,
      title: data.item,
      child: false
    }]
  };

  dataMap[data.section] = newData;
  tableToLoad.push(newData);
}
```

Comment: The `continue` is a little hidden, an explicit `else` might make the workings more obvious.